# Place datepicker values in Listin java

Tags: java, jsp, collections, dictionary, hashmap

say I have 2 date pickers in my front end, where i can select from date and to date. Now i need to place the date fall in between from date to to date in List, is it currently possible. if so how.? tired of searching in google. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
 package com.pkg;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;

public class JanuaryAction {
    private String from; // creating variables to access input values.
    private String to; // creating variables to access input values.
    Map abc1 = new HashMap(); // Getting the map objects to store tha values

    public Map getAbc1() { /* Creating the setters and getters */
        return abc1;
    }

    public void setAbc1(Map abc1) {
        this.abc1 = abc1;
    }

    public String getFrom() {
        return from;
    }

    public void setFrom(String from) {
        this.from = from;
    }

    public String getTo() {
        return to;
    }

    public void setTo(String to) {
        this.to = to;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getAbc() {
        return abc;
    }

    public void setAbc(Map<String, String> abc) {
        this.abc = abc;
    }

    Map<String, String> abc = new HashMap<String, String>();

    Map<String, List<ReportClass>> map = new HashMap<String, List<ReportClass>>(); // Using
                                                                                    // Map
                                                                                    // interface
                                                                                    // implementing
                                                                                    // hashmap

    public Map<String, List<ReportClass>> getMap() {
        return map;
    }

    public void setMap(Map<String, List<ReportClass>> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    public String execute() throws Exception {

        String fromdate = getFrom();
        System.out.println(fromdate);
        String todate = getTo();
        System.out.println(todate);

        Connection con = GetCon.getCon();
        Statement statement = con.createStatement();

        ResultSet resultset = statement
                .executeQuery("SELECT MarketPlace,OrderDate, ROUND(SUM(Total),2), COUNT(*) , ROUND(ROUND(SUM(Total),2)/ COUNT(*),2) FROM vend_printed WHERE OrderDate >='"
                        + fromdate + "' AND OrderDate <='" + todate + "' GROUP BY OrderDate,MarketPlace");

        while (resultset.next()) {
            String marketplace = resultset.getString(1);// get the first column
                                                        // in marketplace
            String orderdate = resultset.getString(2);// get the second column
                                                        // in orderdate
            Double datamount = resultset.getDouble(3);// get the third column in
                                                        // datamount
            Integer count = resultset.getInt(4);// get the fourth column in
                                                // count
            Double result = resultset.getDouble(5); // get the fifth column in
                                                    // result
            ReportClass a = new ReportClass(); // create an object to access
                                                // pojo class.

            a.setMarketplace(marketplace); // setting the values in pojo class
            a.setOrderdate(orderdate);
            a.setDataamount(datamount);
            a.setCount(count);
            a.setResult(result);

            if (map.get(marketplace) != null) { // if the value in marketplace
                                                // is null then go to else
                                                // statement or go to if
                                                // statement.
                map.get(marketplace).add(a); // using the key add one complete
                                                // row values from a to
                                                // marketplace
            } else {
                List<ReportClass> optionsVO = new ArrayList<ReportClass>(); // create
                                                                            // a
                                                                            // list
                                                                            // optionsVo
                optionsVO.add(a); // store Reportclass values in List.
                map.put(marketplace, optionsVO); // storing it in map.
                /* System.out.println(map.get(marketplace).toString()); */
            }

        }
        Set s = map.entrySet(); // A map entry (key-value pair).creating Set
                                // interface.
        Iterator i = s.iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {

            List<ReportClass> tempList = (List<ReportClass>) ((Entry) i.next()).getValue(); // creating
                                                                                            // a
                                                                                            // temporary
                                                                                            // list

            for (ReportClass reportClassObj : tempList) {
                System.out.println(reportClassObj.getMarketplace());// display
                                                                    // values.
                System.out.println(reportClassObj.getDataamount());
                System.out.println(reportClassObj.getOrderdate());
                System.out.println(reportClassObj.getCount());
                System.out.println(reportClassObj.getResult());
            }
        }

        /* System.out.println(map.size()); */
        return "success";
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a TreeMap instead, with a comparator for your Date keys. And post your code to make it work

Comment: We like to see your code

Comment: sorry i needed List not hashmap...any idea?

Comment: are you struggling to extract the values from the map?

Comment: i dont like to use hashmap, i would like to use List but i would get duplicates to avoid that i have to use set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use getters and setters in ur action class for the start and end date then u can play with those values.